# I'm passing a JSON in form data from javascript. And accessing that JSON in php. It replaces "" to &quot

Tags: javascript, php, json

Im sending a array after converting it into JSON using

```
var json_arr = JSON.stringify(info);
```

and JSON is,

```
{"1":"111112221111","2":"1111122211","3":"11111222"}
```

I'm sending this JSON as value of a text box (In form field using post method).

And I'm printing it in a php file as

```
$this->log->write($data['infoArray']);
```

It prints as

```
{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;111112221111&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;1111122211&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;11111222&quot;}
```

I tried

```
json_decode($data['infoArray'],true);
```

but it prints nothing (blank)

so when I'm trying to iterate through it as,

```
foreach ( $data['infoArray'] as $key => $value) {

                    $this->log->write("key :".$key);
                    $this->log->write("value :".$value);
}
```

it throws warning

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So my questions are,

1. why "" are getting replaced by &quot.
2. how can I iterate through JSON so I can access key and value in it.

Comment: Looks like `$this->log->write()` is calling `htmlentities()` on the data before storing. What is `$this->log` an instance of?

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) maybe?

Comment: @castis it is writing value inside () into a log file. Just like we write console.log and it prints it in browser console

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown json_decode() prints blank...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't know what does your `log()` method exactly do so I can't really tell you why.
2. Use `html_entity_decode()` before `json_decode()`-ing the value of `$data['infoArray']`

Try this:

```
$decoded = json_decode( html_entity_decode( $data['infoArray'] ) );
foreach ( $decoded as $key => $value) {
    $this->log->write("key :".$key);
    $this->log->write("value :".$value);
}
```

Comment: this worked like charm....thanks  Log is for writing it into a file just like console.log

Comment: Happy to help :-) Please mark the answer you find most useful as accepted so others could find it easier!

Answer (score 0):

> 1.why "" are getting replaced by &quot.

Actually it's `&quot;` and it's html format for displaying quotation mark. I think JSON wants to keep quots from being mixed with other key values in you JSON array so it replaced them by `&quot;`

> 2.how can I iterate through JSON so I can access key and value in it.

Try [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

So for the warning try to decode html special charaters first, then use JSON decode then use it in foreach:

```
$json_decoded = htmlspecialchars_decode(json_decode($data['infoArray']))
foreach ( $json_decoded  as $key => $value) { ...
```

Comment: read my comment @DontVoteMeDown on my question.... json_decode($data['infoArray']) prints nothing (blank)

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode(json_decode($data['infoArray'])) doesnt work. gives same PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

`infoArray` is a **json string** not an php array (you will have to use `json_decode` php function first to convert the posted json string to php array).

<del>The `&quot;` is added by the `log` function (i guess it is printed in some html), so double quotes are escaped by default (by the function) to `&quot;`</del>

Since JSON is posted as value of textbox the escaping is probably done there and the `&quot;` are replaced there before postinbg to php. Use `html_entity_decode` before using `json_decode`. Although passing json data as part of textfields seems awkward in the first place

Comment: I tried that json_decode($data['infoArray']) prints nothing (blank)

Comment: @Dinesh, can you add this code to your question, maybe it is sth wrong there